# Run Java based Application on mac without having to install Java on it but using bundled JRE instead

Tags: java, macos, eclipse-rcp, packaging, info.plist

I have Java-Maven project made on Eclipse RCP. The project runs fine using Java on the system. But I don't want the client to have to install Java to run that project. So, I have put jdk inside folder, removed Java from the system and played a little with its info.plist file. But everytime I try to run it, it asks to install Java.
I am pretty sure I am making mistakes in info.plist but there might be something else I am missing.

PS - deployment in windows using bundled java works fine.

Comment: Just include Java provided by [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) as part of your RCP application. Add it to your target platform and to your product, like the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ does for example: https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product#n212

Answer (score 0):

It seems eclipse on Mac requires a full JDK, so I don't know if having a full JDK (in place of a JRE..) depoyed in your bundle under `"<eclipse install dir>/jre"`will do the job (To be tested)
Ref: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

If not, you can still bundle your app with a full JDK somewhere under your`"<eclipse install dir>"` and reference`javaw`in `eclipse.ini`, The`"-vm"`stanza accepts relative paths to`javaw`
Ref: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse

Comment: The Eclipse Installer for macOS is a RCP application and contains a Java 17 JRE (not a JDK) with a reduced/minimal system library as a plugin: `org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.macosx.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657`. So I guess the JDK note refers to a Java installed on your system rather than as part of your RCP application.